# How to create user form

Tags: forms

I need to create form with fields
using `Varien_Data_Form` and `Varien_Data_Form_Element_`*

Filds of my form:

- name
- email
- firstname
- lastname
- password
- confirm_password

stucture my file 
      webinse_test.loc  - my project folder

```
           -index.php   - magento file
            ...
            ... another magento files and folders...
            ...
            -Webinseform.php  - this is my form
            -Webinseprocess   - here are must be located all logic with 
                                saving customer to db
```

Code in  Webinseform.php

```
<?php

include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();
class Webinseform  {
public function _conctruct(){
        $form= new Varien_Data_Form(array(
    'id'=> 'webinseform',
    'action'=> $this->getUrl('webinse-test.loc/Webinseprocess.php', 
                array('id'=> $this-    >getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
    'method'=> 'post',
    'enctype'=> 'multipart/form-data'));
        $form->addField('name','text', array('label'=>'Name'));
        $form->addField('email','text',array('label'=>'Email'));
        $form->addField('firstname','text',array('label'=>'Firstname'));
        $form->addField('lastname','text',array('label'=>'Lastname'));
        $form->addField('password','text',array('label'=>'Password'));
        $form->addField('confirm_password','text',array('label'=>'Confirm_password'));
        echo $form->toHtml();
}
}
```

when I enter the URL   http://webinse-test.loc/Webinseform.php   I do not see anything on the display.

Why? Where is form with fields? what am I doing wrong?

**Can I create a form without creating a module? only form**

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Comment: Put error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); to see if there is any PHP error.

Comment: The question shows a lot of missing knowledge about magento development. I recommend you start with the tutorial on magentocommerce.com and afterwards read on alanstorm.com how magento works in details. If you have new questions, just ask again!